# Add methods to dictionary for user selection

Tags: c#

Is it possible to add methods directly to a `Dictionary`? without having to use a more complex delegate solution. I get the error: "`cannot convert to class.method`".

I have a class with a number of methods, given a users input one of these methods should be selected:

Code:

```
class CTARules
{
    public static void TwentyFiftyMA()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    public static void TwentyHundredMA()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

    List<Data_Raw> myList = new List<Data_Raw>();

    Dictionary<string, CTARules> rulesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, CTARules>(){ };
    rulesDictionary.Add("twentyFifty", CTARules.TwentyFiftyMA());
    rulesDictionary.Add("twentyHundred", CTARules.TwentyHundredMA());
```

The idea is of course that if the user selects the `string` which equals the `key` of the `Dictionary`, I can easily fetch the corresponding method to run.

Also, why can't I create my dictionary at class level?

EDIT:

I changed the methods to be called to:

```
public static List<Data_Result> TwentyFiftyMA(List<Data_Raw> myRawData)
{
    List<Data_Result> ResultList = new List<Data_Result>();
    //do stuff with lists
    return ResultList;
}

public static List<Data_Result> TwentyHundredMA(List<Data_Raw> myRawData)
{
    List<Data_Result> ResultList = new List<Data_Result>();
    return ResultList;
}
```

I still get the error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'.  The methods must be able to receive (a) parameters, they can be void methods - same error.

Comment: make your dictionary a `Dictionary<string, Action>` and then use `rulesDict.Add("twentyFifty", CTARules.TentyFifty)`?

Comment: You can add the names of the methods via reflection; I don't think `void` can be used as a variable of any kind. I'm not sure about other types of return values from methods, but in my experience `void` is usually a no-go.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and create a well intended example?
Also, you are asking a second completely different topic question at the end of your question, can you please remove it? Open another question if you think is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your methods are convertible to [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.7.2) delegate, so you can use:

```
Dictionary<string, Action> rulesDictionary
```

While adding methods, do not call them, that will return the result of the method, you can use method groups:

```
rulesDictionary.Add("twentyFifty", CTARules.TwentyFiftyMA);
```

> And why can't I create my dictionary at class level?

Because all executable code should be inside of a method. The declarations inside a class are just metadata, not executable code. You can initialize fields in the class level but that's just a syntactic sugar, the compiler emits the code to the class's constructor.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested. Although I still get the error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'.  Note the edit to question